# Show URL of the Sub site in locally running Publishing site as site column in custom list

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-server, publishing-site, sub-site

There is a requirement to get sub site URL as a site column in SharePoint 2013 Publishing site. Is is possible?

I have tried many alternatives like Site Column: Site, URL, Site URL but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Please add more details to you question. It will help to understand it better.

Comment: On the SharePoint Page, I have added a custom site column name: URL and need to project the site Address where this List is placed in that column.

Comment: Is it the sub site of the same publishing site collection that you are talking about?

Comment: Yes its a subsite of the same publishing site collection and I`m using CQWP to show data from multiple column part of multiple lists.

Comment: An update, my bad as i have replaced the entire code in itemstyle.xsl to show only my style in table format. Not sure if that has impacted the link feature.